# Why is my regexp_replace statement returning \0001?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

My postgresql statement is :

```
update #{table} set email = regexp_replace(email, '.*(\d+).*', 'email_\1@foo.com', 'g') where email like '%@none.com'
```

The result is converting `"placeholder_1@none.com"` to `"email_\u0001@foo.com"`

Where it should be `email_1@foo.com`

Any ideas why it is returning what appears to be unicode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not giving a lot of information here, but given the fact that you tagged this issue with ruby-on-rails, I'll assume that that's what you're using.

If that is the case and if the query you posted above is written in your ruby code in double quotes, then that is the reason:

```
2.6.5 :005 > s = "email_\1@foo.com"
 => "email_\u0001@foo.com"
```

> Double-quote strings allow escaped characters
>
> `\nnn` octal bit pattern, where nnn is 1-3 octal digits ([0-7])

See [ruby string docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings)

If you want to have the actual backslash in your query, you'll need to escape the backslash:

```
query = "update #{table} set email = regexp_replace(email, '.*(\\d+).*', 'email_\\1@foo.com', 'g') where email like '%@none.com'"
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much.